# Python 2.7.6 - Printing a string on a fixed position while creating a dynamic histogram

Tags: python, string

I created a little script that check virtual memory and how much is being used. According to the number that comes back it creates a histogram. The original script creates the following output.

```
VIRT MEMORY USAGE:  43.5
0----------------100%
||||||||
```

However I want the output to be like

```
VIRT MEMORY USAGE:  43.5
0||||||||        100%
```

The problem I am having is that the "100%" is not in a fixed position. It will move left or right according to how many "|"  are being generated by the loop. This does not create the effect desired. :(

The code follows below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psutil
import socket

print "Hostname: ", (socket.gethostname())
print ""
virtu_full_num = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
print "VIRT MEMORY USAGE: ", virtu_full_num
#print "0----------------100%" # From original version of script

number = int(float(psutil.virtual_memory().percent))

for loop_hist in range (1):
     number = number / 10
     print  "0 %s "  % ("||" *number), "   100"
     #print "%s" % ("||" *number)  #From original version of script
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straightforward. Figure out how many space characters there would be between `0` and `100`. For every `|` character you add, remove one space character. Add the two up at the end, and you should be all set.